# How can I override SBT's scalaSource setting for a custom task or configuration?

Tags: scala, sbt

We have a project using Gatling for several sets of performance tests organized into three different directories:

`src/test/scala/
'-one/
  '-perfTest.scala
'-two/
  '-perfTest.scala
'-three/
  '-perfTest.scala`

We're using the Gatling SBT plugin so the task `gatling:test` runs all three tests. What's the best way to be able to run only `one/perfTest.scala` apart from `gatling:testOnly`?

What I've tried:

- Creating a custom task in the `Gatling` config that sets `(scalaSource in Gatling)` then runs `gatling:test`.
- Creating a custom config that extends `Gatling` and then has its own `scalaSource` setting.

In both cases, all Gatling tests ran just as if I'd run `gatling:test` with no changes.

Am I thinking about this entirely wrong? I've tried the SBT documentation, but it doesn't seem very helpful or I have some kind of fundamental misunderstanding of SBT and its config.

Comment: SBT scoping is _hard_... Have you tried `scalaSource in Gatling in test`? Also check the dependencies in `inspect gatling:test`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I just did this

`scalaSource in Gatling := baseDirectory.value / "test/one"`

one is where your gatling tests are

Hope this works.